# Xcode, Swift - Can I hide frameworks within an umbrella framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, embed

There are two frameworks (A, B) embedded in another one (C). I want to use C from my app, and I want to hide A and B.
When I only embed C to my app, it crashes with linker issues like

```
dyld: Library not loaded
Referenced from
Reason: image not found
```

When I add A and B to the target, it works, but I don't want to uncover them. How can I hide them?